# Resizing a webpage to fit in to iPhone screen

Tags: html, iphone, ipad, resize, viewport

I have created a css family tree by going through [this](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree) tutorial. In desktop browsers it looks perfect. [Here](http://ima.emergingscene.com/Islamic_Faith/PropheticFamilyTree/propheticfamilytree.html) is how it looks.

Now I'm trying to make it display the same in iPhone and iPad screens. But when viewing it in those screens, it messes up the layout. Like so.

[image]
[image]

Note that some of the lines connecting the nodes are missing.

I have tried to resize the page using the html meta tags. Tried all the 3 lines below.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=2.3, user-scalable=no">
```

But no avail. I simply need to shrink the page to fit the iPhone and iPad screens. Can anyone please tell me how I can accomplish this?

I have also created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YXyQ9/) here to demonstrate the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You asked in the wrong category :) this is more css then anything else.

I bet you found an answer by now.
But for your fiddle:

```
    .tree {
            width:1100px;
    }
```

Just let me know if you need anything more.
Have a nice day.